# Replacing certain occurence of character with the value of variable using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am writing a bash script to create a csv file from a program.
I have a variable named var which is of the form:

```
var=1,20,40,50,60,70,80
```

Now ,I want to replace first occurrence of ',' with a no. which is stored in variable named j.
Suppose j now has a value equal to 2.
I want var to finally become:

```
1,2,20,40,50,60,70,80
```

I tried doing

```
var=$(echo var| sed 's/,/*/$j,/')
```

But what it did was replace first ',' with $j, instead of replacing it with actual value of j.
How to accomplish this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes or the shell won't expand `$j`:

```
"s/,/*/$j,/"
```